# Значение в пункте списка select

Tags: php, javascript

Есть:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

require_once("components/com_quickform/classes/buildform.php");
$qf = new QuickForm();

echo $qf->getQuickForm((int)$params->get('id'));
```

Необходимо выбирать значение `id` в выпадающем списке.
Попробовал так:

```
<?php  
require_once("components/com_quickform/classes/buildform.php");
$qf = new QuickForm();
?>
<select echo $qf->getQuickForm((int)$params->get());>
  <option value="0" >Перейти</option>
  <option value="get('id')">1</option>
<option value="get('id2')">2</option>
</select>
```

Не работает.

Как правильно сделать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php  
require_once("components/com_quickform/classes/buildform.php");
$qf = new QuickForm();
$id = $qf->getQuickForm((int)$params->get('id'));
$id2 = $qf->getQuickForm((int)$params->get('id2'));
?>
<select>
  <option value="0" >Перейти</option>
  <option value="<?php echo $id ?>">1</option>
<option value="<?php echo $id2 ?>">2</option>
</select>
```

У вас проблемы с синтаксисом кода.
Любые вставки PHP кода внутрь HTML необходимо оборачивать в теги `<?php ?>`

НЕПРАВИЛЬНО

```
<select echo $qf->getQuickForm((int)$params->get());>
    <option value="get('id')">1</option>
```

ПРАВИЛЬНО

```
<select <?php echo $qf->getQuickForm((int)$params->get());?>>
    <option value="<?php get('id') ?>">1</option>
```

Какая-то каша с этими `get()`. Функция возвращает значение или выводит его на экран? Если первое, то его надо печатать `echo get()`

Comment: не работает. Раскрывает данные 'id'. Гляньте сами - справа "Заказ услуги". http://рубеж.com

Comment: @Олег причин неработоспособности может быть миллион и маленькая тележка. Конкретно же в вашем коде была ошибка с выводом значений в html, которую я исправил. Дальше вам необходимо производить диагностику самостоятельно. Смотреть, что возвращается сюда: `$qf->getQuickForm((int)$params->get('id'));`, что выводится в браузер и т.д.

Comment: @Олег поправил код, не заметил еще одной "закладки".

Comment: Так в том то и дело, уже всю голову сломал. Пробовал вставлять формы (items {QuickForm id=01} плагина, который вставляет форму в контент) в отдельный модуль, результат тот же-форма сама раскрывается.